# Stripe\Exception\InvalidArgumentException The resource ID cannot be null or whitespace. #1266

Tags: php, laravel, strip, laravel-cashier

Cashier Version: 13.5
Laravel Version: 8.63.0
PHP Version: 8.0.1
Database Driver & Version: mysql 10.4
When I try to add a new subscription getting the error "The resource ID cannot be null or whitespace.". while trying to do it with the user model it's working fine. But I need to do it with another custom model AppUser. which is pretty similar to the user model.

In the AppserviceProvder under boot method, I have given

```
Cashier::useCustomerModel(AppUser::class);
```

In the AppUser model given Billable and the relation ,

```
namespace App\Models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;

// Authenticatable trait is required to work as User Model
class AppUser extends Authenticatable
{
    use Billable;
    use Notifiable;
    public function subscriptions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Subscription::class, 'app_user_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
```

My subscription Model is

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Cashier\Subscription as CashierSubscription;

class Subscription extends CashierSubscription
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(AppUser::class);
    }

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubscriptionItem::class);
    }
}
```

and

SubscriptionItem Model is

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Cashier\SubscriptionItem as CachierSubscriptionItem;

class SubscriptionItem extends CachierSubscriptionItem
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function subscription()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subscription::class);
    }
}
In My Config/ Auth.php

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'app_user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'app_users',
        ],
    ],

 'providers' => [
        'app_users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\AppUser::class,
        ],

        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'app_users',
        ],
    ],
```

Finally My controller is ,

```
config(['cashier.model' => 'App\Models\AppUser']);

        $data = $request->all();

          $user = AppUser::find($data['user_id']);
        $paymentMethod = $request->input('payment_method');

        $plan = $request->input('plan');
        $plan = $plan ? $plan : 'halfyearly_NZD';

        $response =  $user->newSubscription('main', $plan)->create($paymentMethod);
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long day of debugging, I found the issue.

In my app_users table while creating a new customer I just kept the stripe-id filed as blank. It should be either a stripe id or must be set as NULL.

Another important point, stripe_id filed is highly case sensitive so keep it as utf8mb4_ci encoding